# Sentence construction for a past incident

Tags: tenses

Is the below sentence correct?

"The receiver of my wireless mouse was still plugged into my laptop when i lost it(laptop)?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written is correct but fairly awkward. The reason it is awkward is that the structure of the sentence makes "it" (the thing you lost) inherently ambiguous, potentially referring to either the subject of the sentence (the wireless mouse) or the object (the laptop). Your parenthetical clarifies the ambiguity, but it wouldn't be necessary if the sentence were written differently.

So not wrong, but could be expressed more cleanly. Currently, the reader will wonder what "it" is for a moment before processing the parenthetical.

Instead, try: "At the time I lost my laptop, the receiver of my wireless mouse was still plugged into the USB port."

Schematically the above is: [contextual clause] + [definite subject] + [action] + [unambiguous object].